# Issues with time in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

I'm noticing that there's an issue with the time in my computer. It's changing from 8:xx AM to 02:xx constantly. I used the following command `timedatectl` to see the actual time of the system.

I wonder if there's a bug or something going on with this, as it's a strange behavior

[image: issue_time]

```
diego@diego-G5-5587:~$ timedatectl
                      Local time: vie 2019-07-12 08:17:48 CST
                  Universal time: vie 2019-07-12 14:17:48 UTC
                        RTC time: vie 2019-07-12 14:17:41
                       Time zone: America/Tegucigalpa (CST, -0600)
       System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
diego@diego-G5-5587:~$ timedatectl
                      Local time: vie 2019-07-12 02:18:00 CST
                  Universal time: vie 2019-07-12 08:18:00 UTC
                        RTC time: vie 2019-07-12 14:17:52
                       Time zone: America/Tegucigalpa (CST, -0600)
       System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
diego@diego-G5-5587:~$ ^C
diego@diego-G5-5587:~$ timedatectl
                      Local time: vie 2019-07-12 08:23:20 CST
                  Universal time: vie 2019-07-12 14:23:20 UTC
                        RTC time: vie 2019-07-12 14:23:14
                       Time zone: America/Tegucigalpa (CST, -0600)
       System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Comment: Is it doing this during use, or only after booting? Is the "bios" battery flat, does the bios keep the right time? Might be a conflict between your time servers, what's your `/etc/ntp.conf` say (post to pastebin of it's long).

Comment: I don't have the `/etc/ntp.conf`

Comment: [This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/972336/114740) might help, but I've noticed on my 19.04 that there's no ntp server set in /etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf; I would probably do that as a start .. but it is curious. You could if you need it install ntpd or chrony instead after you `sudo systemctl disable systemd-timesyncd` to disable timesyncd. (check it worked by passing `status` afterwards; it will not start at next reboot, or you can send `stop` to stop it now).